# How do I get the actual byte array from a Windows LPBITMAP or HBITMAP?

Tags: c++, winapi, opencv, bitmap

I'm building a unmanaged windows C++ project that needs to do some analysis on BITMAPS.
The application is NOT a windows application, but rather a win32 library.

Client applications will either pass an HBITMAP of LPBITMAP into the library.

**I need to get access to the underlying byte array[]** for processing and analysis.
How do I get the byte array[] from the BITMAP? (without going to a temp file).

I have been able to do this from a BITMP (.BMP) file.
But in these cases, I need to work with the HBITMAP and LPBITMAP.

**How do I achieve this?**
(Remember that I **don't have access to windows HDC** , et al since this is not a windows app, nor will the library run in conjunction with a windows app)

Can this somehow be accomplished through the opencv library?

Thanks,
 JohnB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `LPBITMAP` then the bits are already there, in `BITMAP::bmBits`.
If you have a `HBITMAP` you can use [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get them.

Comment: Jonathon:: Thx for the response. bmbits is an LPVOID, how do I cast to a byte[]? I'm assuming that bmbits is in fact a byte array?

Comment: Is bmbits the same as the byte[] array that I would get if I directly opened the bitmap file an extracted the bytes?

Comment: Yes it's a byte array, so just use `reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>`. The actual layout depends on the bit depth as documented for the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.